# Why can't I set \C-e in inputrc to be end-of-line for vi-command keymap?

Tags: bash, readline

I have this in my .inputrc, but Control-e doesn't move to end of line in command mode. All other bindings work.

```
$if mode=vi
    set show-mode-in-prompt on

    set keymap vi-insert
    "\C-e": end-of-line
    "\C-a": beginning-of-line

    set keymap vi-command
    "\C-e": end-of-line
    "\C-a": beginning-of-line
$endif
```

I can see it's taking:

```
$ bind -p | grep 'end-of-line'
"\C-e": end-of-line
"\eOF": end-of-line
"\e[F": end-of-line
```

And I can see nothing else is bound to \C-e:

```
$ bind -p | grep 'C-e'
"\C-e": end-of-line
"\C-x\C-e": shell-expand-line
```

If I set it to \C-l, it works. So, what's special about \C-e in readline's vi mode that I'm not able to override?

Only other clue is \C-e causes a terminal beep.

Nothing else is in my .inputrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried and it also does not work for me. But the `bind` command works fine:

```
bind -m vi-command ' "\C-e": end-of-line '
```

Seems like there's something weird in readline loading `.inputrc`. So as a workaround you can put the `bind` command in your `bashrc` files.

Comment: Legend! Thanks. So does that looks like a bash/libreadline bug to you?

Comment: yes it looks like a bash/readline bug to me. you can post it to the gnu [bug-bash](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/bug-bash) mail list and ask Chet to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

According to Chet Ramey via the bug-bash@gnu.org mailing list,

> This has been there forever. The default readline
>   vi command-mode keymap has ^E bound to switch to emacs editing mode. Since
>   bash uses `set -o emacs' for that, the bash readline initialization code
>   unbinds the key sequence. It needs to make sure that the function it's
>   bound to is still rl_emacs_editing_mode.

He provides a patch, which is probably beyond the scope of a SO answer here, so I'll just link to it: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2019-01/msg00217.html

@pynex's workaround works fine.